# Updating SOLR schema using version numbers

Tags: solr

I am designing a SOLR schema for my project, and will create the fields using the Schema-API.

I will likely need to add new fields to the schema in the future.

With SQL databases, I usually store a schema version number in a well-known table.  Then when my app starts up, it checks to make sure the database schema is current.  If not, I execute all of the needed updates (which are numbered) to bring it up to date.

How can I achieve this with SOLR using the schema-api?  Specifically, how/where could I store and retrieve a version number?

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround/solution is to store the version in the name of a SOLR field, for example by creating a field called "schema_version_2".  When my app starts up, I retrieve the list of fields using the [schema-api](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/schema-api.html#SchemaAPI-ListFields) and iterate over them, looking for a field called "schema_version_XX".

Then I can determine whether I need to apply any upgrades to the SOLR schema for my app.  If necessary, my app upgrades to the latest schema version (typically adding/modifying fields).  At the end, I increment the version, for example by deleting the "schema_version_2" field and creating a new field called "schema_version_3".

I would still like to know what pattern and solution developers with more SOLR experience use to solve this problem.

Comment: Beware that the schema API does not report dynamically added fields. If you define a dynamic field `myprefix_*` and a field is created with such prefix (e.g. `myprefix_field_x`) the schema API will not report it in the list of existing fields. Also, take a look at the Luke Request Handler (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler) which I understand is what Solr uses in the Admin interface to show the schema of your Solr core.

Comment: a possible alternative is to create a collection/core with a single document to store the version number and possibly other stuff like schema last update date.